# Asyncio - How detect the end task in another task

Tags: python, micropython

How to detect the end or „is running” of a task that is running in another task. How to detect termination or running task: some_function.run() ?

```
async def service1():

    while True:
    ...
    ap_task = uasyncio.create_task(some_function.run())

    await uasyncio.sleep(0)

async def main():

    tasks = (service1, service2)
        res = await uasyncio.funcs.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)

uasyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Are you looking for an answer that is specific to micro-python, or would regular (cpython)  python sufice?

Comment: Cpython is probably enough. It's about the concept itself ...

Comment: @thomasbartnik Can you correct the indentation or better still show a working example of where you are getting stuck. The `some_function.run()` does not make sense unless this is some class you have created.  Usually when a task finishes it send back its return val. That is when a task is done. You can use a process handler to maintain state if the uasyncio API does it differently to the asyncio API.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a task with `create_task`, you get a task object.

You can then get the status of the tasks using methods such as:

- task.done()
- task.cancelled()
- task.result

See the [full documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object) for details.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I do not have any of these methods available ... gives the tutorial uasyncio v3:
https://github.com/peterhinch/micropython-async/blob/master/v3/docs/TUTORIAL.md#523-cancelling-running-tasks

Comment: emm. That's why I asked if it's micro-python or c-python. Another idea - do you have task._status?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.